# How to sort elements in a bucket of std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, stl, hashtable, unordered-map, unordered-set

After filling STL's **unordered_set< int >** I'm trying to sort elements in each bucket according to a specific order (despite the contradictory container name). It's a know fact that there no changes can be made to the elements in the container and, as far as I understand, it prevents the standard **std::sort** to work. For example next code won't compile:

```
#include <unordered_set>
int main()
{
    std::unordered_set<int> set_;

    set_.max_load_factor(100);

    set_.insert(6);
    set_.insert(3);
    set_.insert(8);
    set_.insert(17);
    set_.insert(1);
    set_.insert(2);
    set_.insert(9);

    for (int i = 0; i < set_.bucket_count(); ++i)
    {
        std::sort(set_.begin(i), set_.end(i));
    }
}
```

So, is there a workaround for that obstacle? Would it be possible to get a temporary sorted list and then assign it to the initial bucket?

Comment: Obviously, you are using the wrong type of container.

Comment: @NeilButterworth not so obviously. only few elements in buckets themselves need to be sorted, not in the whole container

Comment: What's the ultimate goal of this exercise? Why would you care about the order of elements within individual buckets? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik there are some points in it. sure the example above is artificial, but in my real code there is a custom hash function which places the elements the way I need. and the items in the same bucket treated more or less the same and having them sorted will simplify the situation in each bucket

Comment: Note however that "elements in the same bucket" doesn't necessarily mean "elements having the same hash". Having the same hash is sufficient, but not necessary, condition. Most of the time, there are many fewer buckets than there are possible distinct hash values. So I kind of question the "places the elements the way I need" claim.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, in general, that is true. in my case there are never less buckets than the range of values returned from hash function. however, all that makes me think of creating a vector of vectors or something similar. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no API to do what you are doing, because it is a violation of the STL design principle that containers expose an interface, not an implementation.  There is no guarantee that "sorting each bucket" makes any sense in general (even if it is possible in your particular implementation).

If you are sure you need to "sort each bucket" in a hash table, you will need to implement your own hash table.  Given the plethora of open source implementations, this won't be hard.  Where a bucket is often implemented using a linked list, you might use a balanced binary tree.

Answer (score 1):

*"in my real code ... a custom hash function ... places the elements the way I need"* - are you sure about that? - your custom hash function doesn't directly choose the bucket - the `unordered_set` uses it as *an* input to its bucket selection, often doing something like `% bucket_count()`, or perhaps `& (bucket_count() - 1)` as an optimisation if `bucket_count()` is always a power of two.  And you can't necessarily control the number of buckets - calling `reserve(n)` may round `n` up to e.g. a nearby (not necessarily the next) prime or perhaps power of two.  All implementation defined.  That said, you *could* use `bucket_count()` in your hash function to truly control how your keys are grouped into buckets, or only producing hash values less than the `n` you've supplied to `reserve()`, but by the time you're doing that you might as well be managing indices into a `std::vector` of keys.  Anyway, enough of that - let's just trust you do indeed control the hashed-to bucket the way you intend: if you want a sorted list of element from the bucket, you can simple use:

```
std::unordered_map<KeyOnly, AnotherContainer<KeyAndValue>> x;
```

Where `AnotherContainer` is any container that's either inherently sorted (e.g. `std::set`), or can be explicitly sorted in your code in the way you attempt in your question (e.g. `std::list`, `std::vector`).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I’ve finally come to